# Error at git checkout. Path too long

Tags: windows, git, git-checkout

I have this error in Git when I try to checkout to another branch after clone the repo:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false checkout develop

fatal: cannot create directory at 'node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch/node_modules/braces/node_modules/expand-range/node_modules/fill-range/node_modules/isobject/node_modules/isarray/build': Filename too long
```

`node_modules` folder is no longher important to tack into git
(I put the folder `node_modules/` in `.gitignore`) but I always have this error.

It seems a problem of too long path, because if I try to navigate in explorer I meet a windows error of too long path.

Comment: If you're talking about Git for Windows (please always tell us what software package you're using), you could try setting the `core.longpaths` options to `true`. Be sure to read up on it first in the `git help config` manual. Otherwise I'm with @VonC on this.

Comment: I have updated git from 1.7.x to 2.7.4 (embedded git of sourcetree on windows) and now works fine.... maybe `core.longpaths` was not available at 1.7.x version? [link] (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Git-cannot-create-a-file-or-directory-with-a-long-path)

Comment: @padibro I have included your version issue in the answer, as long as a link dating back the origin of the `core.longpaths` config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I put the folder nodemodules/ in .gitignore

You would need to:

- put `node_modules/` in `.gitignore`, not `nodemodules/`
- record the deletion of the `node_modules/` folder from the git repo

  ```
  git rm -r --cached -- node_modules/
  ```

Then you can commit, and try to checkout again.

The [OP padibro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3224058/padibro) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605863/error-at-checkut-path-too-long#comment64614705_38605863) a version issue:

> I have updated git from 1.7.x to 2.7.4 (embedded git of sourcetree on windows) and now works fine

As described in "[Git cannot create a file or directory with a long path](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-cannot-create-a-file-or-directory-with-a-long-path)", [PR 122](https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/122) added `core.longpaths` in Git for Windows only [for git 1.9.0](https://github.com/msysgit/git/releases/tag/v1.9.0.msysgit.0) and more.